Why is the Apple Magic Mouse Unable to Use SwiftUI MagnificationGesture?
This code below works fine with my Apple trackpad, but I am unable to interact with this app using my Apple Magic Mouse. Am I missing something? Why is my Magic Mouse unable to use the SwiftUI MagnificationGesture?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .gesture(
                MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        scale = value
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        scale = 1.0
                    }
            )
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: scale)
    }
}


maybe related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934112/swiftui-magnificationgesture-not-working-properly-on-mac

Does the mouse work with any other Apple environment (AppKit + Swift)?

If you are asking what I am using for programming are swift/swiftui, with my question I am unable to make my magic mouse(apple mouse) could be able use MagnificationGesture, but I am able to tap or drag with mouse and I can use this gestures in my program, but I am unable to take any action with my apple mouse to be able use the MagnificationGesture, can you be able use MagnificationGesture with apple mouse?
